# Script for setting format for two columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, helper

I was using the Copy and Collect review timesheets and updated some of the code/form to give me what I need but for some reason, it's not giving me columns R&S formatted as USD. I tried a few different things but it didn't work?

Can someone take a look and help? This is the base code, the column numbers that need to be formatted as USD are

```
HOURLY_PAY: 18, 
  CALC_PAY: 19,
```

or R + S, see below:

```
`// To learn how to use this script, refer to the documentation:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/timesheets

/*
Copyright 2022 Google LLC

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

// Global variables representing the index of certain columns.
let COLUMN_NUMBER = {
  EMPLOYEE_NAME: 2,
  TOTAL_HOURS: 17,
  HOURLY_PAY: 18, 
  CALC_PAY: 19, 
  APPROVAL: 20,
};

/** 
 * Creates the menu item "Timesheets" for user to run scripts on drop-down.
 */
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Timesheets')
      .addItem('Form setup', 'setUpForm')
      .addItem('Column setup', 'columnSetup')
      .addToUi();
}

/** 
 * Adds "WEEKLY PAY" column with calculated values using array formulas. 
 * Adds an "APPROVAL" column at the end of the sheet, containing 
 * drop-down menus to either approve/disapprove employee timesheets.  
 * Adds a "NOTIFIED STATUS" column indicating whether or not an
 * employee has yet been e mailed.
 */
function columnSetup() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let frozenRows = sheet.getFrozenRows();
  let beginningRow = frozenRows + 1;
  let numRows = lastRow - frozenRows;

  // Calls helper functions to add new columns.
  addCalculatePayColumn(sheet, beginningRow);
  addApprovalColumn(sheet, beginningRow, numRows);
}

/**
 * Adds TOTAL HOURS and CALCULATE PAY columns and automatically calculates
 * every employee's weekly pay.
 * @param {Object} sheet Spreadsheet object of current sheet.
 * @param {Integer} beginningRow Index of beginning row.
 */
function addCalculatePayColumn(sheet, beginningRow) {
  sheet.getRange(1, COLUMN_NUMBER.TOTAL_HOURS).setValue('TOTAL HOURS');
  sheet.getRange(1, COLUMN_NUMBER.CALC_PAY).setValue('WEEKLY PAY');
         

  // Calculates weekly total hours.
  sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.TOTAL_HOURS)
      .setFormula('=ArrayFormula(C2:C+E2:E+G2:G+i2:i+k2:k+m2:m+o2:o)');
  // Calculates hourly rate.
  sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.HOURLY_PAY)
      .setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Settings!A2:B6, 2, false))');
  // Calculates weekly pay.
  sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.CALC_PAY)
      .setFormula('=ArrayFormula(Q2:Q * R2:R)');
  
}

/**
 * Adds an APPROVAL column allowing managers to approve/
 * disapprove of each employee's timesheet.
 *
 * @param {Object} sheet Spreadsheet object of current sheet.
 * @param {Integer} beginningRow Index of beginning row.
 * @param {Integer} numRows Number of rows currently in use.
 */
function addApprovalColumn(sheet, beginningRow, numRows) {
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(COLUMN_NUMBER.CALC_PAY);
  sheet.getRange(1, COLUMN_NUMBER.APPROVAL).setValue('APPROVAL');

  // Make sure approval column is all drop-down menus.
  let approvalColumnRange = sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.APPROVAL,
      numRows, 1);
  let dropdownValues = ['APPROVED', 'NOT APPROVED', 'IN PROGRESS'];
  let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownValues)
      .build();
  approvalColumnRange.setDataValidation(rule);
  approvalColumnRange.setValue('IN PROGRESS');
}


/**
 * Adds a NOTIFIED column allowing managers to see which employees
 * have/have not yet been notified of their approval status.
 *
 * @param {Object} sheet Spreadsheet object of current sheet.
 * @param {Integer} beginningRow Index of beginning row.
 * @param {Integer} numRows Number of rows currently in use.
 */
function addNotifiedColumn(sheet, beginningRow, numRows) {
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(COLUMN_NUMBER.APPROVAL); // global
  sheet.getRange(1, COLUMN_NUMBER.APPROVAL + 1).setValue('NOTIFIED STATUS');

  // Make sure notified column is all drop-down menus.
  let notifiedColumnRange = sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.APPROVAL
      + 1, numRows, 1);
  dropdownValues = ['NOTIFIED', 'PENDING'];
  rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownValues)
      .build();
  notifiedColumnRange.setDataValidation(rule);
  notifiedColumnRange.setValue('PENDING');  
}


/** 
 * Checks the approval status of every employee, and calls helper functions
 * to notify employees via email & update their notification status.
 */
function checkApprovedStatusToNotify() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();

  // lastCol here is the NOTIFIED column.
  let frozenRows = sheet.getFrozenRows();
  let beginningRow = frozenRows + 1;
  let numRows = lastRow - frozenRows;

  // Gets ranges of email, approval, and notified values for every employee.
  let emailValues = sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.EMAIL, numRows, 1).getValues();
  let approvalValues = sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.APPROVAL,
      lastRow - frozenRows, 1).getValues();
  let notifiedValues = sheet.getRange(beginningRow, COLUMN_NUMBER.NOTIFY, numRows,
      1).getValues();

  // Traverses through employee's row.
  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    // Do not notify twice.
    if (notifiedValues[i][0] == 'NOTIFIED') {
      continue;
    }
    let emailAddress = emailValues[i][0];
    let approvalValue = approvalValues[i][0];

    // Sends notifying emails & update status.
    if (approvalValue == 'IN PROGRESS') {
      continue;
    } else if (approvalValue == 'APPROVED') {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, APPROVED_EMAIL_SUBJECT, APPROVED_EMAIL_MESSAGE);
      updateNotifiedStatus(sheet, notifiedValues, i, beginningRow);
    } else if (approvalValue == 'NOT APPROVED') {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,REJECTED_EMAIL_SUBJECT, REJECTED_EMAIL_MESSAGE);
      updateNotifiedStatus(sheet, notifiedValues, i, beginningRow);
    }  
  }
}

/** 
 * Set up the Timesheets Responses form, & link the form's trigger to 
 * send manager an email when a new request is submitted.
 */
function setUpForm() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (sheet.getFormUrl()) {
    let msg = 'Form already exists. Unlink the form and try again.';
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
    return;
  }
  
  // Create the form.
  let form = FormApp.create('Weekly Timesheets')
      .setCollectEmail(true)
      .setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, sheet.getId())
      .setLimitOneResponsePerUser(false);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Employee Name:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Monday Hours:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Tuesday Hours:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Wednesday Hours:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Thursday Hours:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Friday Hours:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Saturday Hours:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Sunday Hours:').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('HourlyWage:').setRequired(true);
 
  // Set up on form submit trigger.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forForm(form)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create(); 
}

/**
 * Handle new form submissions to trigger the workflow.
 *
 * @param {Object} event Form submit event
 */
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  let response = getResponsesByName(event.response);
  
  // Load form responses into a new row.
  let row = ['New',
    '',
    response['Emoloyee Email:'],
    response['Employee Name:'],
    response['Monday Hours:'],
    response['Tuesday Hours:'],
    response['Wednesday Hours:'],
    response['Thursday Hours:'],
    response['Friday Hours:'],
    response['Hourly Wage:']];
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet.appendRow(row);
}

/**
 * Converts a form response to an object keyed by the item titles. Allows easier
 * access to response values.
 *
 * @param {FormResponse} response
 * @return {Object} Form values keyed by question title
 */
function getResponsesByName(response) {
  let initialValue = {
    email: response.getRespondentEmail(),
    timestamp: response.getTimestamp(),
  };
  return response.getItemResponses().reduce(function(obj, itemResponse) {
    let key = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    obj[key] = itemResponse.getResponse();
    return obj;
  }, initialValue);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the **onOpen** function:

```
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let frozenRows = sheet.getFrozenRows();
  let beginningRow = frozenRows + 1;

  ui.createMenu('Timesheets')
      .addItem('Form setup', 'setUpForm')
      .addItem('Column setup', 'columnSetup')
      .addItem('Notify employees', 'checkApprovedStatusToNotify')
      .addToUi();

  sheet.getRange(beginningRow,COLUMN_NUMBER.CALC_PAY,sheet.getLastRow()).setNumberFormat("$0.00");
  sheet.getRange(beginningRow,COLUMN_NUMBER.HOURLY_PAY,sheet.getLastRow()).setNumberFormat("$0.00");
}
```

It will basically get the range from *beginningRow* for the *desired column* up to the *last row with data* and set the dollar formatting with 2 decimal points every time you open the sheet.

Comment: Hi, that didn't work for me, I added it right after "let numRows = lastRow - frozenRows;"

Comment: The location doesn't really matter as far as you have the required parameters :) So it worked right?

Comment: No it still didn’t work as I mentioned above.

Comment: you need to run the columnSetup from the menu again to format the columns since the changes happened after the first time you run the columnSetup.

Comment: It worked when I hit form column setup again, but once I submitted a new form response, it doesn't keep the same format and it goes back to not having it set to $00.00.

I don't want to have to run column setup everytime.

Comment: Ok, i updated the response above and moved everything in **onOpen** function so you don't have to run anything manually. This will format the columns automatically when you **open** the sheet so any new additions from the form will be formatted. This can be done on editing the sheet as well if you want.